# Reorder rows of a table randomly without touching the header line

Tags: tables, tabu

How can I reorder the rows of a table (in my case using tabu package) randomly?

For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{XX}
Header & line \\
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
5 & 6 \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you using LuaLaTeX?

Comment: LuaLaTeX would be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will output randomized lines with each run (I have introduced a new environment for that).

Note: This code will only work with pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, because it uses `randint`.

[image: fun with randomization]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_split:nnN { no }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn { Nx }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_item:Nn { NV }
\cs_set:Npn \processbody #1 {
    \seq_gclear:N \l_tmpa_seq
    \regex_split:noN { \c{\\} } { #1 } \l__student_tmp_seq
    \seq_remove_all:Nn \l__student_tmp_seq { }
    \seq_gpop_left:NN \l__student_tmp_seq \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl\\
    \int_do_while:nn { \seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq < \seq_count:N \l__student_tmp_seq }
        {
            \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \fp_eval:n { randint(\seq_count:N \l__student_tmp_seq) } }
            \seq_if_in:NVF \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_int
                {
                    \seq_gput_right:NV \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_int
                    \seq_item:NV \l__student_tmp_seq \l_tmpa_int \\
                }
        }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewEnviron{randtabu}[1]{
    \begin{tabu}{#1}
        \processbody\BODY
    \end{tabu}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{randtabu}{XX}
Header & line \\
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
5 & 6 \\
\end{randtabu}
\end{document}
```